# What is the differenect between spring cloud and spring cloud Netflix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix

Could somebody explain what the difference between spring cloud and spring cloud netflix? I am just starting to learn and the difference is not very clear for me. The spring cloud is an "interface" (or standart or base implenetation) and Netflix is another "implementation"? Or netflix provide something different things? (what exactly?)

Also Netflix is private company - is there any restriction about using they components? Is spring cloud netflix free?

Comment: Why downvoting without comments?

Comment: I downvoted because you're asking on SO instead of reading the documentation for those two products. That's just laziness on your part.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud different projects under spring cloud. Spring cloud Netflix is one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Cloud is an umbrella project, which consists of several technologies to help developing cloud based applications. Spring Cloud Netflix is a subproject which provides an integration for the Netflix OSS projects (which also consists of several technologies for developing cloud applications, see the [Netflix OSS Center](https://netflix.github.io/)).

Every of those project provides a LICENSE file, which contains the license for that project. In case of Spring Cloud (and i think all other Spring projects) and at least Netflix Eureka, it is Apache License 2.0, which also allows you to use that technologies commercially.

Comment: So in total netflix is complete different comercial service?

Comment: Netflix itself is a commercial service. Netflix OSS are open source projects, which were developed by Netflix and then published to use for other developers (and as i already have said, published under the Apache License 2.0, so you can use them freely).